# Ext-gwt stacked bar chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization, gxt

Anyone knows of a reference/tutorial for making a stacked bar chart in ext-gwt. Also is there any other gwt widget library which supports simultaneous stacked bar chart and line chart.

Answer (score 0):

The chart system in Ext GWT is a wrapper around Open Flash Charts 2. At present I believe the stacked bar chart is not wrapped fully and so not available in Ext GWT out of the box.

Comment: ext-gwt supports the stacked bar chart including line and bar chart